# Toggle between google map polyline and polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As per the answer in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817219/google-map-polyline-not-clearing), I drawn a sample google map polyline as given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/u84wsaLd/10/).
Here I am trying to toggle between polyline and polygon based on radio button. 
I tried to make a another polygon array as,

```
 polygon= new goo.Polygon({
               paths: [],
               geodesic: true,
               strokeColor: '#FF0000',
               strokeOpacity: 1.0,
               strokeWeight: 2
           }),
```

and tried to draw map on clicking of radio button as,

```
if($("#polyline").is(":checked")) {
line.setMap(map);
} else {
polygon.setMap(map);
}
```

Also I set `polygon.getPaths()` with appropriate coordinates in each events. But its gives some error message.

**code snippet** (from [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/u84wsaLd/13/) in comments):

```js
var Line = [];
var polygon = [];

var Latlngs = [];
var Path;

function initMap() {
  var goo = google.maps;
  map = new goo.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new goo.LatLng(12.8799313333, 77.5991386667)
  });
  line = new goo.Polyline({
    path: [],
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    map: map
  });

  polygon = new goo.Polygon({
    paths: [],
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    map: map
  });
  markers = new goo.MVCArray;

  goo.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    var marker = new goo.Marker({
      position: e.latLng,
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    //push new point to the path
    line.getPath().push(marker.getPosition());
    polygon.getPaths().push(marker.getPosition());
    goo.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
      //simply update the path
      line.getPath().setAt(markers.indexOf(this),
        this.getPosition());
      polygon.getPaths().setAt(markers.indexOf(this),
        this.getPosition());
    });
    goo.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function() {
      //remove marker and path-point
      line.getPath().removeAt(markers.indexOf(this));
      polygon.getPaths().removeAt(markers.indexOf(this));
      markers.removeAt(markers.indexOf(this));
      this.setMap(null)
    });
  });

  $("radBut input").click(function() {
    if ($(this).id == "polygon") {
      polygon.setMap(map);
      line.setPath([]);
    } else {
      line.setMap(map);
      polygon.setPaths([]);
    }
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="radBut">
  <input type="radio" name="poly" id='polyline' checked>Polyline</input>
  <input type="radio" name="poly" id='polygon'>Polygon</input>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="map"></div>
```

**EDIT:** I have added one button to clear the drawn line/polygon as

```
     $("#clear").click(function () {
       line.setPath([]);
       polygon.setPath([]);
       for (var i = markers.length; i > 0; i--) {
           markers.removeAt(i);
           markers.getArray()[i - 1].setMap(null);
       }
       Latlngs = [];
   });
```

Once I clear the drawn map and if I draw another line again and trying to delete one marker by double clicking on it, the double click event  not working properly. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/u84wsaLd/17/)

**UPDATE:** The issue in above edit is solved by resetting the marker to `markers = new goo.MVCArray;` as [given here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/u84wsaLd/18/).

Comment: What is the error message?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/u84wsaLd/13/, see console log after drawing polyline

Comment: Why not use the DrawingManager , look at this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a working Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u84wsaLd/16/) where you can switch between polyline and polygon based on your code.

I had to make a few changes to your code to get it to work:

i. Use the `path` property of polygon rather than `paths`
ii. Set the map of the polygon object to null to stop the polygon getting rendered over the top of the polyline (as the radio button is set to polyline)

```
polygon = new goo.Polygon({
    path: [],
    ...
    map: null
});
```

iii. Alter the line of code from `polygon.getPaths().push(marker.getPosition());` to `polygon.getPath().push(marker.getPosition());` as we're now using the path property (not paths).

iv. alter the dragend and dblclick event handler to use `polygon.getPath()` rather than `polygon.getPaths()`:

```
goo.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
    ...
    polygon.getPath().setAt(markers.indexOf(this), this.getPosition());
 });

goo.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function () {
    ...
    polygon.getPath().removeAt(markers.indexOf(this));
    ...
});
```

iv. Modify the `$("radBut input")` event handler to:

```
$("#radBut input").click( function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') == "polygon") {
        polygon.setMap(map);
        line.setMap(null);
    } else {
        line.setMap(map);
        polygon.setMap(null);
    }
});
```

Note that the jQuery CSS selector is now  `$("#radBut input")` not `$("radBut input")` and we use `$(this).attr('id')` to get the id of the selected radio button. Also there is no need to set the polyline or polygon paths to the empty array (this will clear out the polygon or the array points). Instead use `setMap(null);` which will remove the polyline or polygon from the map but maintain the points in the array.

Comment: Thank you. Your sample works fine as required. I also added a button to clear the map. But not working. See the edit in question. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/u84wsaLd/17/

Comment: It is clearing when using `  markers = new goo.MVCArray;` when clicking the button and working fine. Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/u84wsaLd/18/